# SVG replace external file by loaded data

Tags: jquery, svg

I have svg with image tag:

```
<image style="overflow:visible;" width="28" height="28" id="Icon1" xlink:href="ALU41Blk.svg" transform=".... />
```

Now I change some atrributes(or load some other svg icon, doesn't matter):

```
var $img = $('#Icon1');
    var $iconURL = $img.attr('xlink:href');//or some other svg
    jQuery.get($iconURL, function (data) {
        var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');
        $svg.find('path').attr('fill', 'red');//until here everything works
        $img.replaceWith($svg);
    })
```

When I use replace, image is not shown. What function should I use to replace image file with data, I have loaded?